# Flex with spring - layers

Tags: spring, apache-flex, layer, blazeds

I am working with flex \ blazeds that make calls to a server (to a spring + JPA)

Consider the class that catches these calls in java, i.e:

```
@RemoteDestination
public ClassThatCatchesFlexCalls {


public List<UserDTO> getUsers() {
 /// fetch from DB here and return a response to client
}

}
```

In what layer this class is?  Is this part of the Service layer? (serves the client)?
Or is this the Control layer??

Comment: By 'layer' are you talking about aspects of a MVC architecture?  Usually server side classes are considered part of a service layer; which is usually considered part of the model.

Comment: These act as a direct interface for the flex calls(ofcoz directed by the blazeds lib), yes they act as the service layer.